# how to get output of grep command (Python)

Tags: python, grep, subprocess

I have an input file test.txt as:

```
host:dc2000
host:192.168.178.2
```

I want to get all of addresses of those machines by using:

```
grep "host:" /root/test.txt
```

And so on, I get command ouput via python:

```
import subprocess
file_input='/root/test.txt'
hosts=subprocess.Popen(['grep','"host:"',file_input], stdout= subprocess.PIPE)
print hosts.stdout.read()
```

But the result is empty string.

I don't know what problem I got. Can you suggest me how to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should work, are you sure that the user has the access right to read the file?

Also, are you certain there is a `"host:"` in the file? You might mean this instead:

```
hosts_process = subprocess.Popen(['grep','host:',file_input], stdout= subprocess.PIPE)
hosts_out, hosts_err = hosts_process.communicate()
```

Comment: @Shai: yes, you're right. The example was incomplete at best

Answer (score 11):

Try that :

```
import subprocess
hosts = subprocess.check_output("grep 'host:' /root/test.txt", shell=True)
print hosts
```

Comment: is it possible that `check_output` throws `subprocess.CalledProcessError` exception if `grep` finds no occurrence of the string in the file?

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, try Plumbum package(https://plumbum.readthedocs.io/):

`from plumbum.cmd import grep
print(grep("host:", "/root/test.txt"))
print(grep("-n", "host:", "/root/test.txt")) #'-n' option`